# How to config WAMP apache server to allow cross domain requests of ajax?

Tags: apache, sencha-touch, cross-domain, wamp

I am working on an sencha-touch-2.1.0-based application.The application deals with some cross-domain requests.

We wrapped the js files with Android code with PHONEGAP to make the application run in a Android Phone.

And i have installed the wamp server whose apache version is 2.4.4.

I want to test the UI of the app in a Android Phone browser,so i put the **src** files of the sencha touch application in the www directory of the apache server of the WAMP.

But i have got an request error in the console of Chrome in PC:

```
    Origin http://192.168.1.102 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.//192.168.1.102 is the ip of my WAMP server.
```

After hours in google,i find an easy way like

```
`<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</IfModule>`
```

way to alter the httpd.conf of the apache server to allow ajax cross domain requests.
**But it dose not work.** 
So how can i change the httpd.conf of the apache server ?

Comment: Where exactly do we need to add this line of code inside the httpd.conf file?

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right track. The only thing left to do now is to enable the headers module. This can be done as follows:

- click on the wamp icon in your systray
- go to Apache > Apache modules
- check the option 'headers_module'

After you do this, wamp will restart and the configuration you put in your post will work